# Не запускается сервер программ Glassfih из под Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

Поставил сервер программ Glassfish4, настроил, из под консили все запускается как надо.

Подключил сервер в IDEA Intellij (все файлы подключил правильно, вроде), запускаю проект выкидывает всплывающая ошибка от идеи:

> Cannot run program "C:\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" (in directory "C:\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish4\glassfish\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Весь гугл обшарил, ничего годного так и не нашел((

Comment: проверьте, что у вас есть этот файл **C:\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat**

Comment: Да, лично его вручную запускал из под админа (Запустить как админ).
Фишка еще в том, вспомнил, если просто 2 раза кликнуть на батник, то win10 выдаст ошибку "Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again".
Я так понимаю, без админа батники вообще не работают

Comment: как вы устанавливали GF?

Comment: скачав архив, распаковал его на C//:, после в батнике "C:\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish4\glassfish\config\asenv.bat " добавил путь к Java, запустив батник "asadmin.bat"  из под админа вызвал команду start-domain domain1 все запустилось.
В IDEA есть плагин помогающий подключить GF автоматически, остается только указать путь к папкам, батники сами распознаются.

Comment: под каким пользователем вы все это делали? и под каким запускаете IDEA?

Comment: Под единственным пользователем созданным мной при установке Win10, IDEA я пробовал запускать из под админа, но бесполезно(

Comment: Поставил Tomcat - такая же ошибка при попытке запустить сервер из по IDE